# I'd like to produce a function like split (arr, i, j) which divides array arr by axis i, j

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to produce a function like `split(arr, i, j)`, which divides array `arr` by axis `i`, `j`?

But I do not know how to do it. In the following method using `array_split`. It is impossible for me to obtain the two-dimensional array that we are seeking by merely dividing N-dimensional arrays into N-1 dimensional arrays.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(36).reshape(4,9)
dim = arr.ndim
ax = np.arange(dim)
arritr = [np.array_split(arr, arr.shape[ax[i]], ax[i]) for i in range(dim)]
print(arritr[0])
print(arritr[1])
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you show an exmaple using array of what you want to achieve by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to slice array by axis(row, column). Here is the doc. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

```
arr[1,:] # will return all values at index 1(row index 1)
arr[:,1] # will return all values at column 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit here, but it sounds like you want to divide the array into 4 blocks.

```
In [120]: arr = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)

In [122]: [arr[:3,:4], arr[:3:,4:], arr[3:, :4], arr[3:,4:]]
Out[122]: 
[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]), 
 array([[ 4,  5],
        [10, 11],
        [16, 17]]), 
 array([[18, 19, 20, 21],
        [24, 25, 26, 27],
        [30, 31, 32, 33]]), 
 array([[22, 23],
        [28, 29],
        [34, 35]])]
```

Don't worry about efficiency.  `array_split` does the same sort of slicing.  Check its code to verify that.

If you want more slices, you could add more `arr[i1:i2, j1:j2]`, for any mix of indices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like matlab's `mat2cell`? Then you could do:

```
import numpy as np

def ndsplit(a, splits):
    assert len(splits) <= a.ndim
    splits = [np.r_[0, s, m] for s, m in zip(splits, a.shape)]
    return np.frompyfunc(lambda *x: a[tuple(slice(s[i],s[i+1]) for s, i in zip(splits, x))], len(splits), 1)(*np.indices(tuple(len(s) - 1 for s in splits)))

# demo
a = np.arange(56).reshape(7, 8)
print(ndsplit(a, [(2, 4), (1, 5, 6)]))

# [[array([[0],
#        [8]])
#   array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#        [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
#   array([[ 5],
#        [13]]) array([[ 6,  7],
#        [14, 15]])]
#  [array([[16],
#        [24]])
#   array([[17, 18, 19, 20],
#        [25, 26, 27, 28]])
#   array([[21],
#        [29]]) array([[22, 23],
#        [30, 31]])]
#  [array([[32],
#        [40],
#        [48]])
#   array([[33, 34, 35, 36],
#        [41, 42, 43, 44],
#        [49, 50, 51, 52]])
#   array([[37],
#        [45],
#        [53]])
#   array([[38, 39],
#        [46, 47],
#        [54, 55]])]]
```